# Why docker container is not able to access other container?

Tags: docker

I have 3 docker applications(containers) in which one container is communicating with other 2 containers. If I run that containers using below command, container 3 is able to access the container 1 and container 2.

```
 docker run -d --network="host" --env-file  container1.txt -p 8001:8080 img1:latest
    docker run -d --network="host" --env-file  container2.txt -p 8080:8080 img2:latest
    docker run -d --network="host" --env-file  container3.txt -p 8000:8080 img3:latest
```

But this is working only with host network if I remove this --network="host" option then I am not able to access this application outside(on web browser). In order to access it outside i need to make the host port and container ports same as below.

```
docker run -d --env-file  container1.txt -p 8001:8001 img1:latest
docker run -d --env-file  container2.txt -p 8080:8080 img2:latest
docker run -d --env-file  container3.txt -p 8000:8000 img3:latest
```

With this above commands i am able to access my application on web browser but container 3 is not able to communicate with container 1. here container 3 can access the container 2 because there i am exposing 8080 host + container port. But i can't expose again 8080 host port for container 3.

How to resolve this issue??
At last my goal is this application should be accessible on browser without using host network, it should use the **bridge** network . And container 3 needs to communicate with container 1 & 2.

Comment: You should look into `docker-compose`, it was developed for exactly this kind of scenario where you are trying to coordinate multiple containers in tandem. [Official Site](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On user-defined networks, containers can not only communicate by IP address but can also resolve a container name to an IP address. This capability is called automatic service discovery.

Read [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/) for more details on Docker container networking.

You can perform the following steps to achieve the desired result.

- Create a private bridge network.

  ```
  docker network create --driver bridge privet-net
  ```
- Now start your application containers along with the `--network private-net` added to your docker run command.

  ```
  docker run -d --env-file container1.txt -p 8001:8001 --network private-net img1:latest
  docker run -d --env-file container2.txt -p 8080:8080 --network private-net img2:latest
  docker run -d --env-file container3.txt -p 8000:8000 --network private-net img3:latest
  ```
- With this way, all the three containers will be able to communicate with each other and also to the internet.

Comment: This is working but why it is not working in default bridge network. Can u plzzz tell me @Kapil Khandelwal . Thank u so much

Comment: `Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias.`  I **strongly recommend** you to go through the differences between default and user-defined bridges in docker once (https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge)

Answer (score 0):

In this case when you are using --network=host, then you are telling docker to not isolate the network rather to use the host's network. So all the containers are on the same network, hence can communicate with each other without any issues. However when you remove --newtork=host, then docker will isolate the network as well there by restricting container 3 to communicate with container 1.

You will need some sort of orchestration service like docker compose, docker swarm etc.

Answer (score 0):

Communication between containers is simplified with docker compose. By default, it creates a network that allows containers to communicate using the names of services in URLs. For two services, a compose.yaml file could look like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend-dir
    command: *run cmd*
  streamlit:
    build: ./frontend-dir
    command: *run cmd*
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

After running `docker compose up`, you can access the backend from the frontend:

```
HTTP://backend:*backend-port*
```